# prod() function returns a constant number when used in another function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I have a function that returns a product of some values. So I used the function `prod` after computing all values and if I use the function with one specific value, it works perfectly. But when I use it on an interval (for exemple, in the following plot, with geom_function), the function gives a constant, with a warning.

So I tried to iterate the product at each step in the function instead of using prod at the end. And it works without warning.

I was wondering if you have any ideas of why it behaves like that.

I join you the image (in link) and the code I used.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

# Simulation de données
set.seed(1993)
vec <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
index <- rbinom(n = 20, size = 4, prob = 0.4) + 1

# Fonction avec prod
produit1 <- function(vec, index, power) {
  probs <- numeric(length = length(index))
  for (i in seq_along(index)) {
    probs[i] <- vec[index[i]] * power
  }
  prod(probs)
}

# Fonction sans prod
produit2 <- function(vec, index, power) {
  probs <- 1
  for (i in seq_along(index)) {
    probs <- probs * vec[index[i]] * power
  }
  return(probs)
}

# Représentation graphique
abscisses <- seq(-1, 1, 0.1)
fct1_res <- numeric(length = length(abscisses))
fct2_res <- numeric(length = length(abscisses))
for (i in seq_along(abscisses)) {
  fct1_res[i] <- produit1(vec = vec, index = index, power = abscisses[i])
  fct2_res[i] <- produit2(vec = vec, index = index, power = abscisses[i])
}
avec_prod <- ggplot(data = NULL) +
  geom_line(aes(x = abscisses, y = fct1_res), color = "blue") +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) {produit1(vec = vec, index = index, power = x)}, color = "red") +
  labs(title = "Function with prod")
sans_prod <- ggplot(data = NULL) +
  geom_line(aes(x = abscisses, y = fct2_res), color = "blue") +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) {produit2(vec = vec, index = index, power = x)}, color = "red") +
  labs(title = "Function without prod")
avec_prod | sans_prod
```

The plot of the results for each function

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Greetings tend to be discouraged. Remember that this question is meant to be universal and keep them as brief and to the point they are discouraged. See this [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360725/8876321) for a little more info. It may seem impersonal but remember, you may not be the only one who needs an answer to this kind of problem

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about that.

Comment: No problem! It is also in the [Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) I just couldn't find the link at the time.

Comment: The greetings matter is strongly debated, and there are good opinions for both. I personally don't mind them. Anyways, not the issue here. Your recent edit was not necessary - no need to add the answer or "resolved" to the question. By accepting the answer you mark this already! Change/update the question when you want to add new information that was not originally part of your question and which might help to understand your question better. Happy new year. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Also - it was a *good* and very well asked first question!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I'll take all your comments into account if I make another post in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your functions are not vectorized while `geom_function` expects a vectorized functions (see `?geom_function`), i.e. when you call your functions inside the plotting code `geom_function` will pass the vector of `abscisses` to your custom functions. One solution to his issue would be to vectorize your functions so that they work on vectors. The "quick and dirty" approach below instead loops over the `abscisses`:

```r
avec_prod <- ggplot(data = NULL) +
  geom_line(aes(x = abscisses, y = fct1_res), color = "blue") +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) {
    y <- numeric(length = length(x))
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
      y[i] <- produit1(vec = vec, index = index, power = x[i])
    }
    return(y)
  }, color = "red") +
  labs(title = "Function with prod")
sans_prod <- ggplot(data = NULL) +
  geom_line(aes(x = abscisses, y = fct2_res), color = "blue") +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) {
    y <- numeric(length = length(x))
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
      y[i] <- produit2(vec = vec, index = index, power = x[i])
    }
    return(y)
  }, color = "red") +
  labs(title = "Function without prod")
avec_prod | sans_prod
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: erm --- just curious where you added "prod()" ?

Comment: @tjebo `prod` is called in the custom function `produit1`. But I haven't included  in the reprex (or better removed it). (;

Comment: yes, right. Thanks for clarifying. The reprex tag was quite misleading, I admit lol